# How can I get all the indexes of a Particular String in String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

How can I get all the indexes of a Particular String in String Array?

For Ex:

```
String [] alphabet ={“A”,”B”,”C”,”A”,”E”,”A”,”A” };
```

if I am Searching indexes for “A"

so i want result

```
int array [] ={0,3,5,6}
```

Comment: A loop and `equals` ?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(“A")` but it is giving me index of first occurrence of "A" in array.@Jim Garrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `for` loop and `list` to store index like this:

```
String [] alphabet ={"A","B","C","A","E","A","A" };
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) {
   if (alphabet[i].equals("A")) {
    list.add(i);
   }
  }
System.out.println(list);
 }
```

Using a list more betterthan array because you don't need to care about size.
Output:

```
  [0, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: He wants the indexes in int array, not string.

Comment: With compiler error on `List list = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know how many times the `String` we are searching will occur in a `String[]`, I prefer to use a `List` to store all the `indices`. You can try something like:

```
String [] alphabet = {"A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "A", "A"};
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String toSearch = "A";
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  if (alphabet[i].equals(toSearch)) {
    indices.add(i);
  }
}
System.out.println(indices); //prints [0, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through it as suggested and when you encounter the string just save the index (you can use an ArrayList for this, if you want, since we're adding the indeces dynamically).

```
String [] alphabet ={"A","B","C","A","E","A","A" };
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0 : i<alphabet.length; i++){
    if(alphabet[i].equals("A"){ //substitute "A" for the string you are looking for
        list.add(i);
    } 
}
```

The only caveat is that you can't use the primitive type "int" for the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Take and int array[] . And find out your particular String using for loop

```
int[] array;
for(int i=0;i<alphabet.lenght;i++)
{
    if(alphabet[i].equals("A"))
    {
        array[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get exception in the first `array[i]=i;`

Comment: Not to mention this won't work even without the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String [] alphabet ={"A","B","C","A","E","A","A" };
    String search = "A";
    int[] array = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length)
        .filter(i -> alphabet[i].equals(search))
        .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```